# Pythonic way to include imports in python package

Tags: python, pip, python-import, pypi, python-packaging

I am probably missing something obvious here:

I am creating my own python package that I would like to import to [PyPi](https://pypi.org/).
The modules `Foo.py` I have written look like this:

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
--------------
def Class(Foo):
  def function(a: int, b: int):
  '''A class that uses numpy
     to do something with a and b'''
   
    return np.arrange((a + b))
```

When it comes to my package, I am afraid users will run into issues when importing the `Foo.py` module if they do not have `NumPy` installed. What is the best way to include imports in my packages? is it sufficient to import the external modules at the beginning of my module? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to install package dependencies with your package?

Comment: Yes (I guess what I am trying to do is to cause the user the less issues possible)

Comment: Your distribution package (the one you upload to PyPI) must declare `numpy` (and potential other libraries) as dependencies. If you use _setuptools_ for example, then `numpy` should be listed in the `install_requires`. -- This way when someone installs your library (or application) with `pip`, `pip` will be able to obtain the list of dependencies and install those dependencies as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flit](https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/index.html) is a good and modern tool for the job.

https://flit.pypa.io/en/stable/pyproject_toml.html#dependencies

You can specify the dependencies in the `pyproject.toml` file  in the `dependencies` section as below:

```py
dependencies = [
    "requests >=2.6",
    "configparser; python_version == '2.7'",
]
```